# How i install Budgie on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, desktop-environments, budgie

I want test Budgie Desktop on my Ubuntu 15.04 64 bits PC but i can't install due some problems; So, i tried install from several ways:

1. Official PPA: In several guides to install Budgie say that in order to install it type in terminal the commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:evolve-os/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install budgie-desktop
   ```

   The repository adds successfully. Now, i type the last command  `sudo apt-get install budgie-desktop` but returns

   > Unable to locate package budgie-desktop
2. Also i tried build it myself using this commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential gnome-common gobject-introspection libglib2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libpulse-dev libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libmutter-dev libwnck-3-dev libupower-glib-dev libgnome-menu-3-dev libc6-dev
   git clone https://github.com/evolve-os/budgie-desktop.git
   cd budgie-desktop
   ./autogen.sh
   make 
   sudo make install
   ```

   However returned:

   ```
   make: No rule to make target 'install'. Stop.
   ```
3. .deb File:

   After search a lot of guides about this on the web, i found a .deb file available to download, so i downloaded and i open it with Ubuntu Software Center.

   But the Software Center doesn't allowed me install saying the next message:

   ```
   The dependency cannot can be satisfied: libupower-glib1
   ```

   So i go to Synaptic to search it but didn't found the package.
4. Searching in Synaptic.

   Also i tried search the package itself in Synaptic, but wasn't there!.

Recommendation of similar desktops are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ppa, budgie is not currently available for your Ubuntu version.

Here's a snapshot:

[image: 1]

Also, if you really want to install the DE then force install the package using the following command, this will also tell you about all the dependencies. So, then you can install them individually later.

```
sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=package_name package_name.deb
```

**EDIT:**

Well regarding libupower-glib1, its available under archive.ubuntu.com, i.e., it should be available by default. Here is a screenshot to confirm that:

[image: 12]

And about libmutter0d, you are in bad luck, because Launchpad Ubuntu status shows it to be deleted. Here is a screenshot:

[image: 13]

Comment: When i execute these command returned a message saying that budgie-desktop requires the packages "libupower-glib1" and "libmutter0d".             But i don't know how get it. `I tried sudo apt-get install libupower-glib1&&sudo apt-get install libumutter0d` but returned the next message:  _the package libmutter0d isn't available._ Same with libpower-glib1.

Comment: Edited the answer you may check again.